# how do I repeat table with client side template

Tags: jquery, template-engine

```
<h1>product title [once]</h1>
repeating table starts below
<table class="print-names-table">
    <tr class="name">
        <td>Deo</td>
        <td>Nail paint</td>
        <td>Tissue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="num">
        <td>115</td>
        <td>1142</td>
        <td>176</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <span class="total">1433</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I repeat this table multiple times?

Note that in each table "name" row can contain any number of TDs with corresponding TDs in "num" row, and colspan with count of TDs.

What could be a good JSON object for this type of data

Answer (score 0):

You can clone it with JQuery:

```
$('.print-names-table').clone().appendTo('SomeElement');
```